# Ford Taurus 2004 3.0L

Tags: ford, starting, taurus

So i have been having trouble starting my 04 ford taurus. Checked the battery and it is fully charged. It was completely out of oil so i fixed that but still won't start. I just want to start my car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the engine turn over at all (starter moves the engine, but no life signs other than that)? When it was running, did it run well? How did it stop running? Any other information you can give us? Please edit your question and and pertinent details.

Comment: no, the engine does not turn over. the car ran well and everything worked.

Comment: You said it was "completely out of oil" ... how much oil did you add to get it back to level?

Comment: i added 4 quarts.

Comment: Since your car takes 6 quarts of oil, while extremely low, it can live on 2 quarts ... it's not good for your car, but it shouldn't have killed the engine.

Comment: i was told there is a sensor on my car, that whenever the car is running low on oil, shuts down the vehicle for up to 12 hours, to prevent the engine from seizing.

Comment: Oil shut down for 12 hours?  No. That’s not true for that vehicle and model year.

Answer (score 2):

Aight, so I replaced my battery connectors this after noon along with the old battery, and she started right up.
 Thanks for the help